# Limit the upload number of image in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where users can upload their images.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Upload, Button, Form, message } from "antd";

const Uploadd = ({ field }) => {
  const props = {
    name: "file",
    listType: "picture",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
    action: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    onChange: info => {
      console.log(info.file.thumbUrl);

      const { status } = info.file;
      if (status === "done") {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
        console.log(info.fileList);
      } else if (status === "error") {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    }
  };
  const normFile = e => {
    console.log("Upload event:", e);

    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Item
        {...field}
        name={[field.name, "img"]}
        className="upload-img"
        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "img"]}
        valuePropName="fileList"
        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
        rules={[
          {
            required: false,
            message: "Missing speaker image"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Upload {...props}>
          <Button>ADD IMAGE</Button>
        </Upload>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Uploadd;
```

The application works, but i want to customize it, by adding a limit to upload images. Now if user add more than 1 image, every images appears, but i want to display just the last image, so at the end will be displayed just one image.
I found on antd documentation how to limit the number of images: https://codesandbox.io/s/wchbb 
but can't figure out how to implement the data from documentation in my component.
Could somebody help me to achieve what i want?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-feather-pyurt?file=/Uploadd.js:0-1327

Answer (score 0):

As you are using antd to upload file, you can use **maxCount** to limit the number of uploaded files. Will replace current one when maxCount is 1.

```
<Upload
     style={{ width: '100%' }}
     name="imageName"
     accept="image/*"
     customRequest={uploadImage}
     onRemove={()=> setAttachment([])}
     progress={progress}
     fileList={attachment}
     listType="picture"
     maxCount={1}
>
</Upload>
```